# How to get largest value and second largest value to do subtraction?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as following:

```
| event_type | value |                    date |
|------------|-------|-------------------------|
|          2 |    -7 | March, 01 2016 09:00:00 |
|          2 |     4 | March, 01 2016 08:00:00 |
|          2 |    21 | March, 01 2016 07:00:00 |
|          3 |    10 | March, 01 2016 06:00:00 |
|          3 |     8 | March, 01 2016 05:00:00 |
|          4 |    21 | March, 01 2016 04:00:00 |
```

I want to get largest value and second largest value of each event_type to do subtraction as following:

```
| event_type | value |
|------------|-------|
|          2 |   -11 |
|          3 |     2 |
```

Currently, I only can do get largest value of each event_type as following:

```
select event_type, value, max(date)
from events
group by event_type
having (count(event_type) >= 2);

| event_type | value |               max(date) |
|------------|-------|-------------------------|
|          2 |    -7 | March, 01 2016 09:00:00 |
|          3 |    10 | March, 01 2016 06:00:00 |
```

I think I need to know how to get second largest value. Thus, I can do subtraction.

This is my sql fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45e06e/6

Comment: You can use partition by event_type and order by value desc;

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
select event_type, (value - (select e2.value from events e2 where e2.event_type = e1.event_type and e2.date != e1.date order by date desc limit 1)), max(date)
from events e1
group by event_type
having (count(event_type) >= 2);
```

Comment: Your answer is not completely correct but you enlighten me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Window Functions (you didn't mention your database) this is quite easy:

```
SQL> select value from ( 
         select 
            value, 
            row_number() 
               over(partition by event_type order by value desc) as rn 
         from afuncts.employees )x 
     where rn <= 2 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this code work?

```
select event_type, value from 
(select e.*, ROWNUM rnum from events e order by value desc) where rnum = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer:

```
select 
  event_type, 
  (   
     (select 
        e1.value as first_value
      from 
        events e1
      where 
        e1.event_type = e.event_type and 
        e1.date = e.date 
      order by date desc
        limit 1
     ) -   
     (select 
        e2.value as second_value
      from 
        events e2
      where 
        e2.event_type = e.event_type and 
        e2.date < e.date 
      order by date desc
        limit 1
     )
  )
from 
  (     
    select 
      *
    from 
      events
    order by 
      date desc
  ) e
group by event_type
having (count(event_type) >= 2);
```

The sql I can get the newest value:

```
select 
  e1.value as first_value
from 
  events e1
where 
  e1.event_type = e.event_type and 
  e1.date = e.date 
order by date desc
  limit 1
```

The sql I can get the second newest value:

```
select 
  e2.value as second_value
from 
  events e2
where 
  e2.event_type = e.event_type and 
  e2.date < e.date 
order by date desc
  limit 1
```

Therefore, I can use these values to do subtraction.

This is my sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14982/19